# Applying 1 junit-platform.properties file to entire project (multiple modules)

Tags: java, module, junit5

How can I apply a single junit-platform.properties to all modules in my project.

My project has 3 separate modules, each with its own test + resources.

Currently I'm duplicating and placing them in each resources directory. How can I reduce it to just 1 centralized junit-platform.properties and where should I place it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The junit5 guide [4.5. Configuration Parameters](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params) describes

> The JUnit Platform configuration file: a file named
> junit-platform.properties in the root of the class path that follows
> the syntax rules for a Java Properties file.

Therefore you could create a common project with your `junit-platform.properties` and add this project into the classpath for each of your projects.

**for Eclipse workspace**

Create `baseproject` with `junit-platform.properties` file.

[image: common baseproject with junit-platform.properties]

*junit-platform.properties* with custom conmfiguration e.g. `junit.jupiter.displayname.generator.default`

```
junit.jupiter.displayname.generator.default = org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator$ReplaceUnderscores
```

Other project `project2` without any own `junit-platform.properties`

[image: project2 without any own junit-platform.properties]

add `baseproject` to java build path of `project2`

[image: added baseproject to java build path of project2]

[image: order and export of java build path of project2 with added baseproject]

Launching Junit test added `baseproject` into the classpath

[image: classpath of Junit Launcher with added baseproject]

Result of Junit test shows test display name with replaced underscores

[image: result of Junit test showing test display name with replaced underscores]

**for IntelliJ workspace with gradle**

Using IntelliJ workspace , e.g. `junitconfig`.
Add module `baseproject` for `junit-platform.properties` (as resource)
Add module  `project2` for your Java files and Junit test files.

[image: Using IntelliJ workspace junitconfig]

Add module `baseproject` as dependency for module  `project2` in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    implementation project(':baseproject')
}
```

rebuild module  `project2` and run junit test

[image: result of Junit test showing test display name with replaced underscores]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm still quite new to this, to give some more background - the IDE I'm using is IntelliJ. At the same time, I think the solution I'm looking for has to do with the placement of the junit-platform.properties file in a specific location, or by specifying the location in some junit annotation that would allow sharing the file. I'm hoping that my gradle test task would simply pick up on it and apply the properties in my local run and in my gitlab pipeline.

I tried putting the file in my project root folder (not test\resources) but it doesn't get applied at all.

Comment: @WeiChuenOoi I added a description for IntelliJ workspace with gradle

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for!! Where might I read more about how this configuration works? Is it an IntelliJ or Gradle or JUnit or all of the above underlying settings that made it behave as such? How should I understand the flow of the configuration?

Comment: Look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_generate and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931937/how-to-include-module-to-the-project found with google ;)